# Parse Framework throws NSInvalidArgumentException

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I am trying to include the parse framework into an existing iOS App. I followed the Parse iOS Quick Start Tutorial by adding

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  ...
  [Parse setApplicationId:@"..." clientKey:@"..."];
}
```

and than calling

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  ...
  PFObject *testObject = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"TestObject"];
  testObject[@"foo"] = @"bar";
  [testObject saveInBackground];
}
```

of course including the import statements.
Anyway, the problem is that `[testObject saveInBackground];` throws the following exception:

> 2015-05-29 16:39:25.845 shell[306:80175] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** setObjectForKey: key cannot be nil'

I was already searching a lot for a solution for this but cannot find any hint. Also I tried integrating Parse in a new empty project and it worked fine.

Has anyone an idea what could be the problem here?

Comment: Did you create a TestObject class in Parse data browser?

Comment: No I didn't. According to the Parse documentation the class is created automatically, as long as it is not turned of in the settings. Also, with an new empty IOS Project it works fine. I guess the problem is somehow caused by the project setup, which is already pretty old. I was just hoping that someone might know this problem and has a clue.